# What type of images can be created from cameras built using cambits?

Tags: photo-editing, digital, image-processing

Basically I am not very much knowledge in Photography. But I want to know What type of images can be created from cameras built using cambits?

Answer (score 2):

A Cambits camera can only be used if it is connected to a computer. Think of it as a high tech webcam for your computer. It can create almost any kind of image but is restricted by the fact it must be connected to a computer. It is still in development and may never be commercially viable.

This video explains how it can be used:   [Cambits: A Reconfigurable Camera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEFAc3e7Oz4)

[image]